# google cloud deploy ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, google-app-engine, anaconda, panel

I have an [anaconda panel](https://panel.holoviz.org/) application, this works perfectly in the local environment,
but when trying to deploy it with Google App Engine it's giving me errors.

this is the actual [**source location**](https://github.com/thu-vu92/python-dashboard-panel) I modified this to the following

[image]

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: panel serve app.py --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --allow-websocket-origin="*"

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.7

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

**app.py**

```
import hvplot.pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import panel as pn

pn.extension('tabulator')


# cache data to improve dashboard performance
if 'data' not in pn.state.cache.keys():

    df = pd.read_csv(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/co2-data/master/owid-co2-data.csv')

    pn.state.cache['data'] = df.copy()

else:

    df = pn.state.cache['data']

# Fill NAs with 0s and create GDP per capita column
df = df.fillna(0)
df['gdp_per_capita'] = np.where(
    df['population'] != 0, df['gdp'] / df['population'], 0)

# Make DataFrame Pipeline Interactive
idf = df.interactive()

# Define Panel widgets
year_slider = pn.widgets.IntSlider(
    name='Year slider', start=1750, end=2020, step=5, value=1850)
year_slider

# Radio buttons for CO2 measures
yaxis_co2 = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(
    name='Y axis',
    options=['co2', 'co2_per_capita', ],
    button_type='success'
)

continents = ['World', 'Asia', 'Oceania', 'Europe',
              'Africa', 'North America', 'South America', 'Antarctica']

co2_pipeline = (
    idf[
        (idf.year <= year_slider) &
        (idf.country.isin(continents))
    ]
    .groupby(['country', 'year'])[yaxis_co2].mean()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by='year')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

co2_plot = co2_pipeline.hvplot(
    x='year', by='country', y=yaxis_co2, line_width=2, title="CO2 emission by continent")

co2_table = co2_pipeline.pipe(
    pn.widgets.Tabulator, pagination='remote', page_size=10, sizing_mode='stretch_width')


co2_vs_gdp_scatterplot_pipeline = (
    idf[
        (idf.year == year_slider) &
        (~ (idf.country.isin(continents)))
    ]
    .groupby(['country', 'year', 'gdp_per_capita'])['co2'].mean()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by='year')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

co2_vs_gdp_scatterplot = co2_vs_gdp_scatterplot_pipeline.hvplot(x='gdp_per_capita',
                                                                y='co2',
                                                                by='country',
                                                                size=80, kind="scatter",
                                                                alpha=0.7,
                                                                legend=False,
                                                                height=500,
                                                                width=500)


yaxis_co2_source = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(
    name='Y axis',
    options=['coal_co2', 'oil_co2', 'gas_co2'],
    button_type='success'
)

continents_excl_world = ['Asia', 'Oceania', 'Europe',
                         'Africa', 'North America', 'South America', 'Antarctica']

co2_source_bar_pipeline = (
    idf[
        (idf.year == year_slider) &
        (idf.country.isin(continents_excl_world))
    ]
    .groupby(['year', 'country'])[yaxis_co2_source].sum()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by='year')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

co2_source_bar_plot = co2_source_bar_pipeline.hvplot(kind='bar',
                                                     x='country',
                                                     y=yaxis_co2_source,
                                                     title='CO2 source by continent')

# Layout using Template
template = pn.template.FastListTemplate(
    title='World CO2 emission dashboard',
    sidebar=[pn.pane.Markdown("# CO2 Emissions and Climate Change"),
             pn.pane.Markdown("#### Carbon dioxide emissions are the primary driver of global climate change. It’s widely recognised that to avoid the worst impacts of climate change, the world needs to urgently reduce emissions. But, how this responsibility is shared between regions, countries, and individuals has been an endless point of contention in international discussions."),
             pn.pane.PNG('climate_day.png', sizing_mode='scale_both'),
             pn.pane.Markdown("## Settings"),
             year_slider],
    main=[pn.Row(pn.Column(yaxis_co2,
                           co2_plot.panel(width=700), margin=(0, 25)),
                 co2_table.panel(width=500)),
          pn.Row(pn.Column(co2_vs_gdp_scatterplot.panel(width=600), margin=(0, 25)),
                 pn.Column(yaxis_co2_source, co2_source_bar_plot.panel(width=600)))],
    accent_base_color="#88d8b0",
    header_background="#88d8b0",
)
# template.show()
template.servable()
```

Once I run `gcloud app deploy` this error came:

[image]

[image]

Then I downgraded in **requirements.txt**

```
panel==0.12.0
bokeh==2.3.3
hvplot==0.7.2
aiohttp==3.8.1
aiosignal==1.2.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==21.4.0
backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.1
base58==2.1.1
bitarray==1.2.2
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
commonmark==0.9.1
cytoolz==0.11.2
distlib==0.3.4
eth-abi==2.1.1
eth-account==0.5.7
eth-hash==0.3.2
eth-keyfile==0.5.1
eth-keys==0.3.4
eth-rlp==0.2.1
eth-typing==2.3.0
eth-utils==1.10.0
filelock==3.4.0
frozenlist==1.2.0
haralyzer==2.0.0
hexbytes==0.2.2
idna==3.3
ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2
jsonschema==3.2.0
lru-dict==1.1.7
multiaddr==0.0.9
multidict==5.2.0
netaddr==0.8.0
numpy==1.21.6
pandas==1.3.5
parsimonious==0.8.1
pipenv==2021.11.23
pipenv-poetry-migrate==0.2.0
platformdirs==2.4.0
polygonscan-python==1.0.2
protobuf==3.19.4
pycryptodome==3.13.0
Pygments==2.11.2
pyrsistent==0.18.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.20.0
pytz==2022.1
requests==2.27.1
rich==9.13.0
rlp==2.0.1
six==1.16.0
tomlkit==0.10.1
toolz==0.11.2
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
uniswap-python==0.5.5
urllib3==1.26.8
varint==1.0.2
virtualenv==20.10.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.7
web3==5.26.0
websockets==9.1
yarl==1.7.2
```

Then ended up with not available **polygonscan-python==1.0.2**

[image]

Is there any way to upload these packages into Google Cloud, without downloading like this, how to solve this?

Comment: Please don't include screenshots in questions. It requires others to manually duplicate content (e.g. `requirements.txt`) that should have been copy-pasted in the first place. Screenshots are also likely to not outlive the question. Please add the original `requirements.txt` file and include the commands (preferably in a local virtualenv) where you were able to build the solution and satisfy the requirements. Cloud Build appears to be correctly unable to reconcile the package versions and this issue should reproduce locally too (since the environments should be similar|identical).

Comment: Are you using App Engine standard or flexible?

Comment: @its app engine, let me add files for this

Answer (score 0):

The version of `numpy` you first tried to use, and the [`polygonscan-python`](https://pypi.org/project/polygonscan-python/) package require Python3.8. Your GAE Flex environment is built for Python3.7, so pip can't install these packages without [meeting](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#satisfying-requirements) the requirements.

Unfortunately, the base Python Docker image that can be used in GAE Flex [only supports up to Python 3.7.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime/issues/225). So, your application can't run as you have set it up.

GAE Standard, however, supports the [latest](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime) Python runtime (3.10). I tested deploying your app in the Standard environment and could get it running. Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: @kez were you able to deploy your app to App Engine?